# ¿Cómo solucionar error en Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, gridview, crystal-reports

Estoy trabajado en poder importar unas filas de un GridView a formato PDF
Pero me sale este error:

> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ParameterFieldCurrentValueException

Según me dice que es por los parámetros, pero al ver lo que me pide en los parámetros del método le paso los correctos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
foreach (int i in gvDispositivos.GetSelectedRows())
{
    string nombreHojaResguardo = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";
    ReportDocument Rpt = ImprimirConsentrado(ObtieneConcentrado(i), sDepartamento, sPuesto, sNoEmpleado, sMacAddress);
    Rpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, nombreHojaResguardo);
}
```

`gvDispositivos` es mi GridView y solo ocupo los renglones que estén seleccionados
`ObtieneConcentrado()` es un método que trae los datos del Grid en base a los seleccionados
`ImprimirConsentrado()` genera un DataSet con los datos de las filas seleccionadas del Grid

Y bueno, cuando llega a la parte de exportar me marca el error que menciono al principio

¿como se soluciona ese error?

Comment: Por favor intenta encerrar tu código en un bloque `try/catch` e imprime el error completo así: `catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); } ` . También puedes buscar "ParameterFieldCurrentValueException" - desconozco Crystal Reports.

Comment: Probablemente tienes parámetros definidos en tu reporte, no veo que los estés mandando en tu código, esa debe ser la causa